# Django REST Framework Authentication keyword

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token, bearer-token

I'm trying to rename the Rest_framework TokenAuthentication keyword from "Token" to "Bearer" as suggested in the Documentation I have subclassed the TokenAuthentication class like this:

in module: user/authentication.py

```
from rest_framework import authentication

class TokenAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    """
    Simple token based authentication.
    Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization"
    HTTP header, prepended with the string "Token ".  For example:
    Authorization: Token 401f7ac837da42b97f613d789819ff93537bee6a
    """

    keyword = 'Bearer'
```

in module app/settings.py

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'user.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
     ),
 }
```

It is still sending me a 401 Unauthorized when im using 'Authorization: Bearer ...token...' but not with 'Authorization: Token ...token...'

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post you views code also?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have also used TokenAuthentication in the authentication_classes in every View

Comment: Odd. This is all I needed to do to change the `TokenAuthentication` for my entire project. I did not need to add anything to the views.

Comment: same problem here? did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one last step. Import your `TokenAuthentication` class that contains the new keyword in your `View` class instead of the default `TokenAuthentication` class.

Answer (score 4):

from rest_framework import authentication

class TokenAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):

```
authentication.TokenAuthentication.keyword = 'Bearer'
```